# How to sum for previous n number of days for a number of dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a list of dates each with a value in Postgresql.

[image: 1]

For each date I want to sum the value for this date and the previous 4 days.

I also want to sum the values for the start of that month to the present date. So for example:

- For 07/02/2021 sum all values from 07/02/2021 to 01/02/2021
- For 06/02/2021 sum all values from 06/02/2021 to 01/02/2021
- For 31/01/2021 sum all values from 31/01/2021 to 01/01/2021

The output should look like, will be created as two separate tables:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5pYa.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you tag Postgresql when your dbms is mysql?

Comment: Sorry was meant to say Postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Sample data and structure: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2a2a3edb0bcdf1c46167d7d50ffaaa4e)

**For first part of query:**

```sql
select date,
       value,
       sum(value) over (
           order by to_date(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
           rows between 4 preceding and current row) as five_day_period
from your_table_name
order by to_date(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') desc;
```

**For second part of query:**

```sql
select date,
       value,
       sum(value)
       over (
           partition by regexp_replace(date, '[0-9]{2}/(.+)', '\1')
           order by to_date(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
           rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as month_to_date
from your_table_name
order by to_date(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') desc;
```

Comment: Did this query work? @Jay